# npm install <git> with dev dependencies

Tags: node.js, github, npm

A typical approach to handle private npm modules is to put them to a Git repository, and then use `npm install` with the path to that repository to install the module.

If you enter the dependency into your `package.json` file, you can even install using `npm install` without the need to specify the repository url every time. I.e., if you add

```
"myPrivateModule": "git+ssh://git@github.com:myGitHubAccount/myPrivateModule.git"
```

as a dependency, you can install using

```
$ npm install myPrivateModule
```

and everything works fine :-).

Now I have a problem in that `myPrivateModule` is private, yes, but not a dependency. Instead, it's a dependency only for development time, hence I put it into the section `devDependencies` in the `package.json` file.

Once you do this,

```
$ npm install myPrivateModule
```

does not work any longer, as it now searches the public registry instead of using the registered path to the repository.

Is there a possibility to make this work, without the need to specify the full-blown path each and every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `npm install` with no arguments should read `package.json` and install it.

Comment: This does not work once the modules have been installed, and all you want to do is update `myPrivateModule` to its newest version.

Comment: It will if you tag your releases and include the tag at the end of the URL: `git+ssh://git@github.com:myGitHubAccount/myPrivateModule.git#v1.2.3"

Comment: Not able to get this to work - `npm i git+ssh://git@github.com/centralcollegenottingham/HTML-Email-Boilerplate-Redux#master --save` (or --save-dev) will install no dev deps

Comment: That's a different command. If you put that URL in your package.json devDependencies then run `npm install` with no arguments, it will get installed. `npm install <url>` means something different.